# How to set iOS UITextField border color? (RubyMotion + iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, rubymotion

How to use RubyMotion to set a textField border color?

Example code:

```
textField = UITextField.alloc.init
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine
```

The border color shows up as the Apple default color; I want it to be red.

This is using RubyMotion, not Objective-C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Quartz framework.

In your Rakefile:

```
app.frameworks << 'QuartzCore'
```

To set the layer attributes:

```
textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor.CGColor
textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```