# How to translate iOS Objective-C category interface code to RubyMotion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

Objective-C uses a "category" interface to add new methods to existing classes:

```
@interface ClassName (CategoryName)
@end
```

Example to add a "hello" method:

```
@interface XYZPerson (HelloWorld)
- (NSString *)hello;
@end
```

RubyMotion does not have "categories" nor interfaces in the same exact way.

How does RubyMotion code provide similar functionality?

Comment: What is the point of all your self-answering RubyMotion questions?

Comment: @DarkDust One can create a QnA type of questions. That's encouraged. However, I am not sure this question really needed to be asked.

Comment: To help other people. What I'm finding as I'm learning is that StackOverflow can benefit from more RubyMotion info. Is there a smarter or better place for these kinds of questions and answers?

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson This place is fine. But not sure if Objective C specific patters have place in other languages.

Comment: [How to set the border color of a UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236117/how-to-set-ios-uitextfield-border-color-rubymotion-ios) and [how to set the placeholder color of UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236456/how-to-set-ios-uitextfield-placeholder-color-rubymotion-ios) are about the API (Cocoa Touch). Do you want to ask and answer all kind of Cocoa Touch API questions only because you're doing it RubyMotion instead of Objective-C? This question is about language features which indeed is a bit more interesting that the other two.

Comment: @Leo Thanks, what I tend to find on SO is that when I create a QnA, it creates a way for other people to add better info.

Comment: @DarkDust No, just QnA that was non-obvious to me after research here on SO and also elsewhere. As you may know there's much less RubyMotion info on the net.

Comment: So… why don't you accept the answers to your questions then if they're solving the questions?

Comment: @DarkDust SO blocks that; SO says there's a two-day wait before I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RubyMotion has similar functionality.

Use typical Ruby to re-open a class to add a method:

```
class XYZPerson
  def hello
    # return a string
  end
end
```

If you prefer to modularize the code, or to use the same code in multiple places, you can use a Ruby module:

```
module Hello
  def hello
    # return a string
  end
end

class XYZPerson
  include Hello
end
```

Be aware that RubyMotion file load order is important. For example, if you define the same method more than once, the new definition will overwrite the old definition.

Comment: To extend your comment, load order is also important in Objective C, where the order classes and their categories are loaded, the newest implementation takes. This is sometimes called "undefined behavior", although it is defined. `:-)`